# bootstrap collapse event fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I created a menu with collapsible items in which the arrow will change on click

- Collapse closed : `fa-caret-right`
- Collapse opened : `fa-caret-down`

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    ....
    <li>
        <a href="#level2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Level 2</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="level2" data-parent="#parent">
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ....
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function ()
{
    $(this).prev().find('svg').addClass('fa-caret-down').removeClass('fa-caret-right');
});     
$('.collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function ()
{
    $(this).prev().find('svg').addClass('fa-caret-right').removeClass('fa-caret-down');
});
```

The problem is that when I click on a sub element, the event is fired two times, not only for the current element but also on the parent.

[image] [image]

As you can see in the images, when I closed level 2, the event was also applied to level 1 and the icon changed from `fa-caret-down` to `fa-caret-right`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding `event.stopPropagation();` at the beginning of the event.

This way the event is applied only to the selected element.

```
$('.custom-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();            
    $(this).prev().find('svg').addClass('fa-caret-down').removeClass('fa-caret-right');
});

$('.custom-collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();            
    $(this).prev().find('svg').addClass('fa-caret-right').removeClass('fa-caret-down');
    $(this).find('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `find` method searches through all descendants of element. So this will find not one, but two SVG and add/remove classes:

```
$(this).prev().find('svg').addClass('fa-caret-down').removeClass('fa-caret-right');
```

You can try using first() method to get first element.

```
$(this).prev().find('svg').first().addClass('fa-caret-down').removeClass('fa-caret-right');
```

Comment: I was able to fix this by adding `event.stopPropagation();`